# How to structure a query that results a date range like a chort?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have an invitations table with a created_at timestamp.

I want to query by a weekly cohort, meaning all records in the given week needed. Example

- LAST WEEK
- 2 WEEKS AGO
- 3 WEEKS AGO

This is what I have so far:

**LAST WEEK**

```
SELECT *
FROM invitations
WHERE created_at >= curdate() - INTERVAL dayofweek(curdate()) + 6 DAY
AND created_at < curdate() - INTERVAL dayofweek(curdate()) - 1 DAY
```

**2 WEEKS AGO**

```
SELECT *
FROM invitations
WHERE created_at >= curdate() - INTERVAL dayofweek(curdate()) + 13 DAY
AND created_at < curdate() - INTERVAL dayofweek(curdate()) - 1 DAY
```

**3 WEEKS AGO**

```
SELECT *
FROM invitations
WHERE created_at >= curdate() - INTERVAL dayofweek(curdate()) + 18 DAY
AND created_at < curdate() - INTERVAL dayofweek(curdate()) - 1 DAY
```

I believe this is not working correctly as this is querying for all records, not just the records in that given week. Is there a better or easier way to do this type of query by weekly cohort?

Comment: I don't get it... can you please post sample data and the desired result with that data?

Comment: Why don't you use just `curdate() - INTERVAL 7 DAY`? you mean the start of that 1,2,3 week?

Comment: @JorgeCampos I love that idea, how would I update the WHERE clause to use this... Something like: 
Week1: 
WHERE created_at >= curdate() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
AND created_at < curdate() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
Week 2:  
WHERE created_at >= curdate() - INTERVAL 7 DAY
AND created_at < curdate() - INTERVAL 14 DAY

Comment: I think you almost get it. `created_at >= curdate() - INTERVAL 7 DAY AND created_at < curdate() - INTERVAL 1 DAY ....` see the difference?

Comment: love it, so much better. Thanks